How do I make products update with setProducts(update)
In the following REACT code, setProducts(update), is not updating products.  products is remaining the same original value.  How do I update products to be the old values and the new element?
let PHOTO = [
 
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "name1",
        imageUrl: require ("./test.png"),
        price: 25,
        options: [{option:'option1' , checked: true}, {option:'option2' , checked: false}, {option:'option3' , checked: false}, {option:'option4' , checked: false}],
        category: "art2",
        amtstars: "none"
        
        
      },

      {
      id: 2,
      name: "name2",
      imageUrl:  require ("./test.png"),
      price: 180,
      options: [{option:'option1' , checked: false}, {option:'option2' , checked: false}, {option:'option3' , checked: false}, {option:'option4' , checked: false}],
      category: "art2",
      amtstars: "none"
      },
];

let [products, setProducts] = useState(PHOTO) 

var update = [

  ...products,

   {

    id:product.id,
    name: "aaa",
    imageUrl: require ("./test.png"),
    price:  2599,
    options: [{option:'option1' , checked: check1}, {option:'option2' , checked: check2}, {option:'option3' , checked: false}, {option:'option4' , checked: false}],
    category: "art2",
    amtstars: amtString
  }

]

//this is not updating products
setProducts(update)


What is the indication that products is not updating? Like, are you logging something out, or noticing that some part of the page that you expected to update doesn't update?

When I hover over products it is just the original two elements.

Are you saying you set a breakpoint and then hovered over the products variable? If so, what line is the breakpoint on?

The breakpoint is right after the last line.

products is a local variable which contains a snapshot of what the state was when the component rendered. It will never change, and setProducts does not try to change it. Calling setProducts just asks react to render the component again. When that second render happens, you will make a new local variable with a new snapshot of the state. If you'd like to verify that the component is rerendering, put your breakpoint in the body of the component (eg, on the line right after you call useState)

I'm not understanding.  Doesn't setProducts set the products value?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Every time the component renders, you make a new local variable named products. Calling setProducts only changes what products will be on the next render. It has no effect on the variable from the current render. I've linked another stack overflow question which has more details. This is also discussed in react's documentation of useState

In this example, the rerender is not rendering the new element.

I am unable to reproduce
